# Norm in the space of square integrable martingales

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I was learning stochastic integration and encountered two different norms used in the space of square integrable martingales They are as follows:

1.Let M be a square integrable martingale, then $|M|_t$ : = $\sqrt{ \mathbb{E}[M_t^2]}$

$$|M|:=\sum_1^\infty \frac{{1\wedge |M|_n}}{2^n}$$    ($\wedge$ is minimum)

And,

2. Let M be a square integrable martingale, then $|M|$ : =$\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[\sup_{t < \infty}M_t^2]}$.

Are these two norms equivalent

Comment: is this a discrete time process?

Comment: @Timkinsella No continuous time.

Comment: Do you mean $t<\infty$ instead of $t\leq T$ in the last line? if not, what is T?

Comment: @Timkinsella Yes I have edited

Comment: For the second norm, should it not be $|M| := \sqrt{\mathbb{E} \left[\sup_{t \geq 0} M_t^2\right]}$? I do not see how the triangle inequality holds unless the norm is the square root of the right-hand side. If this is the case, then the second norm is strictly stronger than the first and I'll answer with the proof.

Comment: @Shiva Yeah sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity I will denote the first norm as $\left|\cdot\right|_a$ and the second as $\left|\cdot\right|_b$, i.e. for a square-integrable martingale, $M$
$$\left|M\right|_a = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1\wedge \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left[M_n^2\right]}}{2^n} \quad\quad \left|M\right|_b = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \geq 0}M_t^2\right]}.$$
The second norm is *strictly* stronger than the first meaning that there exists a $C>0$ such that for any square-integrable martingale $M$, $\left|M\right|_a \leq C\left|M\right|_b$, but the reverse, $\left|M\right|_b \leq C' \left|M\right|_b$, is not true.

Since for both norms $|M| = \left|\left(M - M_0\right)\right| + \left\|M_0\right\|_{L^2}$, we can assume that $M_0 = 0$.  Let $\left<M, M\right>$ denote the quadratic variation of $M$. We will apply two facts about quadratic variation 1) $\mathbb{E}\left[M^2_t\right] = \mathbb{E}\left<M,M\right>_t$ and 2) $\left(\left<M, M\right>_t\right)_{t \geq 0}$ is an increasing process.

$$\left|M\right|_a = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1\wedge \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left[M_n^2\right]}}{2^n} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1\wedge \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left<M,M\right>_n}}{2^n} \leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left<M,M\right>_n}}{2^n} \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left<M, M\right>_\infty}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{t \geq 0}M_t^2\right]} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{c_2}}\left|M\right|_b$$
The last inequality follows from the Burkholder–Davis–Gundy inequality for $p = 2$ and $c_2$ is the corresponding universal constant (see for example [IV.4 in Revuz and Yor](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540643258) or [5.3.3 in Le Gall](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319310886)).

The other direction necessary for equivalence fails for Brownian motion, $B$, as $|B|_a = 1$ but $|B|_b = \infty$.